# Can't post in Android TV

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an android TV application which need Facebook share function. It's no problem to call the post function by using Facebook SDK. The problem is the users are still not able to post because they don't have mouse and keyboard and there is no touch screen for them to press the **"Post"** button.

[image]

The reason is very simple. Users are not able to move focus to **Post** button because it doesn't accept focus. Is there any way to solve the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Interesting, this is most likely an issue with the Facebook app. You can file a bug over at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the FB SDK isn't ready for AndroidTV.  I was having issues even getting FB Login to work on AndroidTV.  How are you even able to sign-in the user via the webdialog on AndroidTV?

See my question here [Android Facebook SDK 3.23.0 - FB Login on AndroidTV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991063/android-facebook-sdk-3-23-0-fb-login-on-androidtv)

The issue is most of the operations with the FB SDK will be performed in a webview since the native Facebook application isn't installed on the AndroidTV device.  This makes sense, because who wants to use Facebook on a TV (my person opinion anyway).

Until Facebook gives us the ability to use their SDK via AndroidTV by updating their SDK to support a TV platform I'm pretty sure you'd have to build all this stuff out in a custom way by manually calling the Graph API with whatever functions you'd like to do with it.

I don't have the time to do this right now, so you know what happens....I hide the Facebook Login button in my app until I can get to it.  Pretty crappy isn't it?