# Android Facebook SDK 3.23.0 - FB Login on AndroidTV

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-tv

Does anyone have any experience using the Facebook SDK to perform Facebook login on AndroidTV?

Since it's most often the case that an AndroidTV user won't have the actual Facebook app installed on the AndroidTV device, the Facebook SDK will open a WebView to allow the user to enter his Facebook credentials and login.

The issue is the webview that gets displayed doesn't respond to d-pad actions and the fields to enter text don't indicate they are selected.

Am I to assume that Facebook login for AndroidTV just isn't possible using the standard Facebook SDK functionality?

Comment: I'm stuck in the same problem. How did you solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Also, Facebook API currently does not support Android TV. So it'll not be possible for you to build an app with Facebook Login on Android TV (unless you wanna write your own library for it). Hence, no D-Pad support and the messed up function of the text fields.

Comment: Well, seems like you are correct.  What do I do now....hide the facebook login button in my app's login procedure.  Pretty damn crappy Facebook :-P

Comment: Depends... what all devices does your app support?

Comment: The target build for this specific binary is for AndroidTV only.  I'm not going to remove FB login from my mobile app.

Comment: Well, in that case... if this binary is just targeting AndroidTV, then yes, remove/hide the FB login button. I'd say comment out the code so you may be able to use that functionality when it becomes available but it depends on how you've written it and what kinda dependencies you might have to take care of.

Comment: Yep, this isn't my first time at the rodeo ;-)

But you do make a very good point about writing good code!

The code is written well enough so that all we will have to do is hide the Login with FB button.  The FB code will still be in-use by our mobile binary anyway (the mobile and TV binaries are built with the same core library which contains all of the FB stuff).  Hopefully FB will update the SDK soon enough so that we don't have to spend too much time on doing a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is taken directly from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html#advertising)

> Note: You can use the WebView class for logins to services like Google+ and Facebook.

I assume they are suggesting the use of a `WebView`, but not necessarily by means of the Facebook SDK (whose `WebView` might be custom/limited).

Answer (score 1):

You can login with facebook on android tv, to do this you must first enable logging in from devices.
Products - Facebook Login - Settings - Login from Devices - set to yes.

And for logging in you must use the DeviceLoginManager.

```
mDeviceLoginManager = DeviceLoginManager.getInstance();
        mDeviceLoginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, facebookCallback);
 mDeviceLoginManager.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.DEVICE_AUTH);
        mDeviceLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

This will open a webview with a code.
[image]

Comment: it crashes at         mDeviceLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Collections.EMPTY_LIST); line

Comment: Stacktrace @Anonymous ?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was very helpful:

The solution was to execute the following javascript on my WebView in

```
onPageFinished():

webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('email')[0].focus();");
```

> Obviously this will only work with the Facebook sign in screen, since
>   they have a text field with name 'email'.

[Source](http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/6cae8173c8f7/android-how-can-i-trigger-focus-on-a-text-input-field-in-a-webview-after-page-.html)