# How to use facebook SDK for android TV apps

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-tv

I want to use facebook login for my TV app. I have integrated the facebook API and it runs fine on emulator but I'm unable to enter text on TV with remote, seems like it does not support the Dpad options. 
Does anyone know a good solution for it.

Comment: Facebook login is supported, please check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47013463/2704885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is supported yet as you can see in this [Improving Facebook Login on TV and Android](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/10/27/login-for-tv-and-android/) post, Facebook SDK currently supports [log-in and sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tvos) as of now. No other functionality was mentioned like remote control operations.